# Approaching arrays nested in a struct

Tags: c#

I am not sure if I am using struct in a right way. Anyway I need a struct of which one property is an array consisting of another struct. Somehow I can't approach one of the property in a nested struct.

```
struct Clients
    {
        int client_number;
        public ArrayList accounts;
    }

struct JsonStruct
    {
        public ArrayList clients;
    }

var obj = new JsonStruct();
obj.clients[0] = new Clients();
obj.clients[0].client_number = 100; // this last line does not work..
/* it throws this kind of error:
 "object does not contain a definition for client_number.."
*/
```

obj.clients[0] should now have Clients' structure but it seems it does not.

Comment: In JsonStruct replace “clients” with “Clients”

Comment: This helps with error ?

Comment: You dont have `Clients` in `JsonStruct`, so you can't access it from there

Comment: An ArrayList is not an array. It is far worse than an array. You said you needed an array. An array of `Clients` would be written as `Clients[]`. If you need it to grow and shrink use a `List<Clients>`.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the struct object (obj) also has to be convertible into JSON.

Answer (score 0):

After reading OP's comments and requirements I came to this solution:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class structCheck
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = new JsonStruct();
        obj.clients.Add(new Clients());
        obj.clients[0].client_number = 100;
        Console.WriteLine(obj.clients[0].client_number);
    }
}

class Clients
{
    public int client_number;
    public List<int> accounts = new List<int>();

}

class JsonStruct
{
    public List<Clients> clients = new List<Clients>() ;

}
```

> **OUTPUT:**
>
> 100

Do let me know if you want to add something.

Comment: Thanks, I already figured that out too.. The crucial line missing was:  `obj.clients.Add(new Clients());`

Answer (score -1):

There are 4 things you have to change:

1. Make `client_number` public, otherwise it cannot be accessed by your
   code
2. Change the error line to: `((Clients) obj.clients[0]).client_number = 100;`. Since ArrayList contains items of type `object`, you must cast them back to `Clients`
   Make
3. Make Clients a class instead of a struct. Otherwise you will get an error: "Cannot modify the result of an unboxing conversion". structs are value types, therefore, if you cast an bject to a struct, like in step 2, you will get a copy, not the original, and the assignement statement makes no sense.
4. Recommended: Change ArrayList to List. Non.generic collections like ArrayList are outdated, and generic collections should be used. The you can omit the cast from step 2.

The new code will look like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Clients
{
    public int client_number;
    public ArrayList accounts; // maybe you ma want to change this to a list<T> as well
}

class JsonStruct
{
    public List<Clients> clients;
}

var obj = new JsonStruct();
obj.clients[0] = new Clients();
obj.clients[0].client_number = 100;
```

Comment: what OP wanted is `struct` if it had been a `class` then there should be no issue... he asking about nested structs and you changed the whole code to classes

Comment: @ZainArshad: He writes: "I am not sure if I am using struct in a right way.". structs are value types, therefore he will never be able to change any value if he stores them in an ArrayList, like he does, because unboxing will return a copy of the struct.

To answer the question using structs, it would be necessary to learn more about why it must be structs, not classes..

You are welcome to offer him a better answer than mine using structs.

Comment: " I need a struct of which one property is an array consisting of another struct"...

Comment: I don't insist on struct specifically, so if this solution with classes is convertible to JSON, I have no problem with that.

Comment: @ZainArshad C# structs are usually misused by people with a C++ background. In C#, you really shouldn't use structs unless you have very good reasons to do so. OP's code does not look like there was one such reason. In fact, a struct with a nested reference is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: Even if I tried your solution, the line with `obj.clients[0] = new Clients();` does not work.Throws exception: _System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object._

Comment: The final result should be object that can be converted to a JSON structure that looks like this: 

`{
  "clients": [
    {
      "client_number": 123456789,
      "accounts": [
        {
         ....
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "client_number": 123456789,
      "accounts": [
        {
         ....
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}`

Comment: @Totallama you must first *initialize* clients: `obj.clients = new List<Clients>()`;

Comment: The line with: `obj.clients[0].client_number = 100;` throws exception:
_System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection_

Comment: The last lines have to be changed as follows:
`var obj = new JsonStruct();
obj.clients = new List<Clients>();
obj.clients.Add( new Clients() );
obj.clients[0].client_number = 100; `
Note that this works, but is still no good programming style. You should move as much as possible into your classes, e.g. the creation of the List<Clients>